# How do you display your overlay logo on embedded videos?

Tags: dailymotion-api

I can't seem to find any documentation anywhere that states how you can display your overlay logo with link when embedding your video?

After attempting to copy the URL format used on the [overlay settings](http://www.dailymotion.com/settings/logooverlay) page, however it always reverted back to the DailyMotion logo.

```
http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/<video_id>?
    GK_PV5=1&
    api=postMessage&
    apiKey=<apiKey>&
    origin=<origin>&
    ui-watermark_link_url=<link_url>&
    ui-watermark_url=<watermark_url>
```

To clarify, is the logo only displayed when the video is shown on the DailyMotion website, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

To put on overlay on your Dailymotion videos, you don't need any code, it's only a setting in the overlay settings page you mention: http://www.dailymotion.com/settings/logooverlay

You need to have monetization enabled to access this feature.

Basically, you only have to upload your logo on this page (when logged) and this will add a logo to the bottom right corner of your videos (whether onsite or in your embeds).

Read more at https://faq.dailymotion.com/hc/en-us/articles/207322227-Logo-overlay

Comment: Hi @Dailymotion - that's all setup correctly, as it appears correctly on all of our videos on our channel, including on the logo overlay settings page, however any video's embedded on another website, shows the DailyMotion logo?

Comment: alright, this is weird. I've check and it's working on my side. Then you should see with your contact at dailymotion if you have one, or fill in a request at https://faq.dailymotion.com/hc/en-us/requests/new so someone here can check

Comment: Hi @DailyMotion, sent an email and was advised that it had been escalated however I haven't heard back, even after requesting an update (two weeks ago), anything you can help with?